# How to create makefile in cooja?

Tags: c, makefile, contiki, rssi

I am trying to make program for rssi measurement in cooja. Recently, I found that the makefile is a must for running the programs, but the /contiki/examples has so many examples with different makefile contents. For instance, "collect" uses certain apps in makefile. How to understand the apps and tools needed for my work? Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that this is a too generic question to answer here. You'll have to spend some time to learn about makefiles. Google for "writing makefiles". Then you might want to do some research, instead of letting others do you homework and come across https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/Contiki-Build-System. Oh, and before you do RSSI-Measurements in Cooja you probably want to do some research on simulation of RSSI-values - with Cooja in particular, too.